# Python script using boto3 stopped producing results

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I have this python script that I use to collect info on the `EC2` instances for my `Beanstalk` applications.
It worked perfectly fine for a long time, and then it simply stopped producing results, but it throws no errors and there are no authentication problems.

What am I missing? Was there a change to the API?

The script is below:

```
import boto3

regions = ['us-east-1','us-west-2']

for region in regions:
    ebs_client = boto3.client('elasticbeanstalk', region_name=region)
    ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)

    apps = ebs_client.describe_applications()
    print(apps)

    for app in apps['Applications']:
        appname = app['ApplicationName']
        print(appname)
        envs = ebs_client.describe_environments(ApplicationName=appname)

        for env in envs['Environments']:
            envname = env['EnvironmentName']
            envid = env['EnvironmentId']
    [... some more code ...]
```

Right on the first call to `describe_applications` it returns a `200 OK` status code but with zero results. And I have a lot of Beanstalk apps running in those regions.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. It had to do with the credentials used.
I removed them and used the Instance Role instead and it worked.

Still weird, though. Because there should be an error somewhere instead of producing zero results.

Comment: I'd be tempted to test this code with a deliberately bad, or expired, set of credentials in order to work out where the bug is (presumably in your code) that's causing errors to be suppressed.

Comment: Well, you presumed wrong. The code is good. The credentials were not, but there was no error whatsover thrown, and there should be in my opinion.

Comment: It may still be worth investigating why these credentials do not fail. The symptoms suggest that the credentials are valid, but perhaps they are for an account that has zero EB applications in those 2 regions. If I run this code with an invalid access key I get InvalidClientTokenId. If I run it with valid access key but incorrect secret key I get SignatureDoesNotMatch. If I run it with expired STS credentials, I get ExpiredToken.